# NETGEAR ReadyNAS SSH connection closes immediately

Tags: ssh, readynas

I've installed the [Enable Root SSH Access](http://www.readynas.com/?p=4203) plugin to my ReadyNAS Ultra 4. It used to work, but now I'm only getting this message:

```
$ ssh tomas@192.168.1.3
tomas@192.168.1.3's password: 
Last login: Fri Sep 13 20:07:33 2013 from 192.168.1.16 on pts/0
Linux leviathan 2.6.37.6.RNx86_64.2.4 #1 SMP Thu Jul 26 05:00:36 PDT 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Last login: Fri Sep 13 20:07:55 2013 from 192.168.1.16
Connection to 192.168.1.3 closed.
```

The connection is closed immediately, never giving me a chance to input any commands. The only change that has happened since SSH worked (that I know of) is updating the firmware of the NAS. Also, the SSH plugin isn't showing up in the "Installed Add-ons" list. Any chance the firmware update screwed up the SSH plugin? I successfully installed the plugin again, but with no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that was embarrassing. I just realized I have to connect using the root user, as the name of the plugin suggests.

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.3
root@192.168.1.3's password: 
Last login: Fri Sep 13 20:30:42 2013 from 192.168.1.16 on pts/0
Linux leviathan 2.6.37.6.RNx86_64.2.4 #1 SMP Thu Jul 26 05:00:36 PDT 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
leviathan:~#
```

After you login as the root user, you may edit `/etc/passwd` and give your user account(s) a valid shell rather than the default of `/bin/false`. Once you do that, you can ensure local user accounts don't have bad permissions on their respective `.ssh` directories and then they may also get an interactive login. (You may also use password authentication.)

Change root's password — it defaults to the same default for `admin` and you don't want that.